# How can I prevent the default behavior when i am navigate inside the react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I've react 18.2 and I am using functional component. I am trying to prevent the default behavior of the event when a user is trying to navigate to an external link or inside the React app. My code works fine when I refresh the page, but when I navigate to another route inside the app from the header, it's not showing modal.

changes you made may not be saved.

```
import { useLocation, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const location = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();

const { id } = useParams();


useEffect(() => {
  const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
    if (!id) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = '';
      return '';
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
  };
}, []);
```